# Ошибка с кодировкой при запуске приложения Flask на операционной системе Windows 7

Tags: python, flask

Установил Фреймворк Flask на Виндовс 7. При попытке запустить сервер вылетает ошибка UnicodeDecodeError:

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: invalid start byte.

При этом старался форматировать python-файл (скрипт) в программе Notepad++, менял кодировку на "ПРЕОБРАЗОВАТЬ В UTF-8 без DOM"

[image: Запускаемый файл]

И даже в начале кода  прописывал строку `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`, но эта ошибка так и вылетает! Помогите решить эту задачу!

[image: Запуск в командной строке]

Comment: не нужно скриншоты использовать, которые только из текста состоят. Это делает вопрос менее полезным (пока гуглбот не научился автоматически текст в картинках индексировать). Добавьте код и traceback в виде текста, с соответствующим форматированием

Answer (score 1):

`coding: utf-8` указывает кодировку *исходного* кода.

Она не имеет *никакого* отношения к другим кодировкам, которые могут быть использованы во время исполнения, например, к кодировке, используемой для имени компьютера или к кодировке, используемой для отображения в Windows консоле или к кодировке, используемой notepad по умолчанию (три разных несвязанных значения).

В Питон 3, utf-8 является кодировкой по умолчанию для исходного кода поэтому объявление кодировки можно убрать. В исходном коде нет не ascii символов, поэтому декларацию кодировки можно убрать и в Питоне 2 в этом случае.

Код приложения выглядит нормально. Traceback указывает, что проблема в декодировании доменного имени.

Пример показывает, что в данном случае имя *возможно* начинается с русской буквы A, закодированной используя Windows кодировку (cp1251 для русской Винды по умолчанию):

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(b'\xc0'.decode('cp1251'))
'CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER A'
```

Попытка декодировать, используя utf-8, естественно завершается ошибкой:

```
>>> b'\xc0'.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Если не рассматривать [IDN-имена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN), то имя компьютера должно состоять только из ascii символов. Чтобы обойти проблему, можно попробовать переименовать машину.

Для проверки можно использовать

```
T:\> py -3 -mhttp.server
```

или

```
T:\> py -3 -mhttp.server --bind 127.0.0.1
```

Или же вызвать код напрямую в Питон-консоле (например, `py -3 -midlelib`):

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.getfqdn()
'example.com'
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('127.0.0.1')
('localhost', [], ['127.0.0.1'])
```

Для тестирования, можно явно `host` указать:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True)
```

Comment: C:\>py -3 --mhttp.server --bind 127.0.0.1

Comment: C:\>py -3 --mhttp.server --bind 127.0.0.1                                          Ошибка: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: invalid start byte    При других действиях получается тоже самое. Так же запускал ваш код в консоли питона и все-равно ошибка та же...В чем может быть дело?

Comment: @Alexander: эта команда *должна* эту ошибку показывать (её назначение -- воспроизвести ошибку без участия flask): шаг №1 переименовать машину, чтобы только латинские буквы были (ascii), шаг №2 запустить `py -3 --mhttp.server --bind 127.0.0.1` **для проверки**, чтобы убедиться что проблема решена.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!!!! Наконец-то заработало......