# UnicodeDecodeError при запуске нового Django-проекта на Windows

Tags: python, windows, django

Создаю новый проект на Django c помощью PyCharm. Ничего не меняю. При запуске проекта выбивает ошибку:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.3\bin\runnerw.exe"
C:\Python34\python.exe E:/Projects/Proj_test/manage.py runserver 8000

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until
they are applied. Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
January 23, 2016 - 12:55:37
Django version 1.9.1, using settings 'Proj_test.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper
at 0x036E9078>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 467, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Аналогичная ситуация при использовании Visual Studio. Смена версии Python не решает. Использую Windows 7.

Подскажите, как можно решить данную ошибку.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Unicodedecodeerror with runserver](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23109244/4279)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Ошибка с кодировкой при запуске приложения Flask на операционной системе Windows 7](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/424208/23044)

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109244/unicodedecodeerror-with-runserver

Comment: Смотрите ответ выше - Автор user339204 - best solution)
Что за нездоровые сложности? Просто файл питона редактируется не в utf-8.
Смотрите настройки своего текстового редактора, которым открываете файлы и дописываете русские символы. У меня проблема пропала.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Проблема состояла в том, что имя компютера было указано кирилицей. Поменял на латиницу и все ок.

Comment: Угрохали 3 часа на эту фигню со студентом, а решение такое незамысловатое! Спасибо, спаситель.

Answer (score 13):

Это баг в Питоне 3.4+: [Windows: socket.gethostbyaddr(name) fails for non-ASCII hostname](http://bugs.python.org/issue26227).

В качестве workaround, [попробуйте передать имя хоста как ip-адрес (например, `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000`) или переименуйте хост, чтобы в имени не было не-ASCII символов.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23109559/4279)

Comment: согласен с Вами, тут проблема всё-таки в ранних версиях python3, в них вообще достаточно много проблем с кодировкой. В данном случае в модуле socket.
Рекомендую обновлять python, так, например, обновление версии 3.5.1 до 3.5.3 решает данную проблему для python 3.5

Comment: Хм, а [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/810836) аналогичная ошибка уже на Python 3.6

Comment: А [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/886748) уже на Python 3.7, странно

Comment: А [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1149740) и на 3.8.3... А, ну баг уже переоткрыли в марте 2020-го :)

Comment: В 3.8.11/3.9.6 кажется таки починили, ура)

Answer (score 5):

В приведенном  выводе ошибок можно заметить:

> You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until
>   they are applied. Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

и также:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position
>   0: invalid continuation byte

Скорее всего действительно проблемы с кодировкой.

Видимо в файле русская буква В (в кодировке cp1251, характерной для винды), а вот где-то в недрах проекта указано, что ожидается кодировка utf-8...

Comment: UTF8 кодировка указана в самом Питоне. Это [был баг](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/565643/23044)

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая же была проблема Windows 8. Поменял имя юзера на латинском языке не помогло.
В дебаге обнаружил, что в файл utf-8.py подается путь с кирилицей C:\Users\Пользователь.
В переменную input подставил путь. И все заработало.

```
def decode(input, errors='strict'):
    try:
        codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)

    except:
        input='c://windows'
        pass
    return codecs.utf_8_decode( input, errors, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

что то какие то сложные ответы. Зачем все это когда можно просто открыть нужную страницу в Notepad++ и преобразовать её в utf-8 ведь debugger описал что суть его проблемы только в том что он встретил символ в какой то кадрировке которая не совсем похожа на unicode

Answer (score 0):

В windows 10 была похожая ошибка при попытке запуска отладки (shift + F9) в PyCharm, когда интерпретатор был настроен через docker-compose.
Получал ошибку вида:

```
.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 494: invalid start byte

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Причем запуск (shift + F10) кода работал, а отладка нет.

Проблема оказалась в том что имя Windows пользователя было написано кириллицей. И PyCharm пытался подхватить файл docker-compose.override по пути содержащим русские буквы, что приводило к ошибке.

Помогло создать нового пользователя Windows у которого имя на английском.