# django запуск с сервера

Tags: python, django, сервер

Так у меня python 3.4. Я установил Django с cmd.Создал проект оттуда.Manage.py все есть. Хочу runserver не работает:

```
django-admin startproject first
cd first
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver
C:\Users\help\Desktop\django-ex\firstsite>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 14 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until yo
 apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
January 11, 2018 - 13:31:40
Django version 2.0.1, using settings 'firstsite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrappe
 at 0x000000000450C8C8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in
wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver
py", line 143, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 16
, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 66
 in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 429, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 135, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 460, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 5: invalid
continuation byte
```

Браузер не видит 127.0.0.1

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: ['utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte при запуске нового проекта на Django](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485310/utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xc2-in-position-0-invalid-continuation-byte-%d0%bf%d1%80)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Django Open Server не нужен.. И да, ошибка у вас простая. Вы не сделали миграцию..

Пропиши `python manage.py migrate` а потом снова запусти..

Он не запускается потому, что у тебя в БД нет нужных начальных таблиц от Django. И запуская свой сервер, он заранее предупредил что у тебя есть несколько не примененных миграций:

```
have 14 unapplied migration(s). 
Your project may not work properly until yo apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions. 
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Нужно сделать миграцию чтобы появились новые таблицы в БД который он автоматически создает, а потом можно и запустить сервер.

Comment: сработало!!блогадарю

Comment: Миграции - дело, конечно, нужное, но к UnicodeDecodeError отношения не имеют

Comment: опять проблемы с уникодами что то....

Comment: Код покажи начальный свой.. Так будет трудно гадать

Comment: Я правил вопрос посмотри

Comment: localhost:8000 или 127.0.0.1:8000 пропиши.. Всмысле не видит?

Comment: страница не найдена. Пишет

Comment: А что в консоли? Может ты сервер забыл запустить?

Comment: Да я пишу runserver после те ошибки выдаются

Comment: Ты можешь код показать?) Нужен сам Django код, то что ты сам написал в views.py

Comment: @GunduzAbdullayev что если запустить как `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: Я там ничего не написал только в Cmd startproject migrate  и все

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Сработало!!! Отличноо блогадарю обоих за труд