# Не могу открыть ни один Django проект, сами проекты енкодил в UTF-8, но не помогло

Tags: python, django, utf-8

Не могу открыть ни один Django проект, сами проекты енкодил в UTF-8, но не помогло

С другого ноутбука все работало, не понимаю куда лезть и что менять

Винда стоит 7, если это важно

Терминал выдает

[image: скрин терминала]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: учту на будущее, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что имя вашего компьютера содержит кириллические символы.

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло