# Запуск тестового сайта на Django в виртуальной среде Python 3 (Windows 7)

Tags: django

Пожалуйста ответьте на мой вопрос. Установил виртуальную среду для Python 3.7 в Windows 7, затем установил в нее Django 2.2.5.  Затем попытался запустить сервер.
В итоге терминал выдал такие строчки:

```
(ll_env) C:\python_works\Learning_log>python manage.py runserver

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 18, 2019 - 12:19:59
Django version 2.2.5, using settings 'learning_log.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\python_works\Learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autor
eload.py", line 54, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\python_works\Learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\manage
ment\commands\runserver.py", line 139, in inner_run
ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)
File "C:\python_works\Learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\server
s\basehttp.py", line 203, in run
httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
File "C:\python_works\Learning_log\ll_env\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\server
s\basehttp.py", line 67, in __init__
super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
self.server_bind()
File "C:\Python37\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
File "C:\Python37\lib\http\server.py", line 139, in server_bind
self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
File "C:\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 676, in getfqdn
hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: 
invalid continuation byte
```

Сайт не запустился. Даже не представляю, с какой стороны подступить. Если возможно, прошу ответить. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: имя компьютера кириллицей?

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [UnicodeDecodeError при запуске нового Django-проекта на Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485310/unicodedecodeerror-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-django-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-windows)

Comment: Большое спасибо за оперативный ответ, вернее вопрос. Он оказался ответом. Все работает.