# Не удается запустить локальный сервер Джанго

Tags: django

Не удается запустить локальный сервер Джанго, после ввода python manage.py runserver набираю в поисковике 127.0.0.1.:8000 . Выдает нет подключения,а в командной строке UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: небось ms/windows и небось какой-то из файлов начинается с символа `и` (cp1251) или `ш` (cp866).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [UnicodeDecodeError при запуске нового Django-проекта на Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485310/unicodedecodeerror-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-django-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что файл manage.py не в формате UTF-8
Тебе необходимо открыть его и "Сохранить как.." и выбрать тип UTF-8