# Не запускается сервер Django, помогите разобраться, какие нужны изменения?

Tags: python, django, python-3.8

Не могу разобраться,возможно с декодированием...(Имя пользователя написано на латинице)
Работаю из под Win7, установлен python3.8.3, редактор pycharm.

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

July 06, 2020 - 22:32:36

Django version 3.0.8, using settings 'ab.settings'

Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

Exception in thread django-main-thread:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Vibe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()

  File "C:\Users\Vibe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Vibe\PycharmProjects\1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Vibe\PycharmProjects\1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 138, in inner_run
    run(self.addr, int(self.port), handler,

  File "C:\Users\Vibe\PycharmProjects\1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 206, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)

  File "C:\Users\Vibe\PycharmProjects\1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 67, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Vibe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()

  File "C:\Users\Vibe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)

  File "C:\Users\Vibe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\server.py", line 140, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)

  File "C:\Users\Vibe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 756, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 5: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [UnicodeDecodeError при запуске нового Django-проекта на Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485310/unicodedecodeerror-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-django-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-windows)

Comment: Дьявольский префикс от винды..."имя пользователя"-ПК
Проблема решена шоколадкой и горячим чаем!:)

Comment: У меня точно такая же проблема. Win 7, python 3.8.5 попытка запустить локальный сервер. Имя пользователя на латиннице, все папки тоже. Через блокнот пробовал перекодировать все файлы проекта сначала в utf-8, потом все остальные кодировки перепробовал. Не помогло. Переустановил винду, установил пайтон и джанго заново. Тоже не помогло(ошибка та же) Я новичек и делаю это первый раз. Если кто знает как решить, опишите пожалуйста по подробней(без этого не могу двинутся дальше)