# Почему django не может декодировать байты при запуске сервера?

Tags: python, django

django==3.1.4, python==3.8.2
При создании проекта django-admin startproject startup летит следующая ошибка:
[image: изображение]
При чём и имя компьютера, и остальной путь написан латиницей
Также пробовалось явно указывать адрес: python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [UnicodeDecodeError при запуске нового Django-проекта на Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485310/unicodedecodeerror-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-django-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-windows)

Comment: А вообще попробуйте установить более новую версию питона (3.8.10 или 3.9.5), там вроде уже починили

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Вопрос решился, у имени компьютера был префикс -ПК, после его удаления всё заработало