# Не запускается локальный сервер Джанго

Tags: django, веб-сайт

Всем привет.
Не  запускается стартовая страница Джанго, локальный сервер(зелёная ракета с текстом что всё установилось)

В браузере: страница не найдена, Техническая информация: ошибка connectionfailure

В терминале: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: invalid start byte

Делала всё по видео уроку на Ютуб. Видела ответ на похожий вопрос - сохранить manage.py в UTF-8,как это сделать?

---

```
Django version 3.2.18, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Python project\millon\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python project\millon\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 140, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)
  File "D:\Python project\millon\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 210, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "D:\Python project\millon\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 71, in init
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in init
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\server.py", line 139, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 676, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Покажите полный текст ошибки

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [UnicodeDecodeError при запуске нового Django-проекта на Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485310/unicodedecodeerror-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-django-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-windows)